# How to avoid a big log file with WAL archiving?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, enterprisedb, postgres-plus

I enabled WAL archiving in EDB Postgresql 9.6 for PITR, but now every time a 16MB log file is created and filling Disk volume. How do I avoid that?

These are the changes made to `Postgresql.conf` to enable the wal archive:

```
wal_level = replica
archive_mode =  on
archive_command = 'cp %p /postgres/cluster/wals/%f'
```

(cp from `pg_xlogs` to `wals` folder)

Now the wal folder is filling every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You avoid filling up the destination directory by

- providing enough disk space there
- deleting WAL archives you don't need any more.

PostgreSQL does not automatically delete WAL archives for you — it does not even know where they are.

Comment: we configured similar in testing environment but without any data in database how come log files are being created everyday.

Comment: I don't know about which database your question is, but WAL is generated whenever anything in the database is modified.

Comment: -rw------- 1 edbpostgres edbpostgres  16M Apr  2 20:00 000000020000000000000018
-rw------- 1 edbpostgres edbpostgres  16M Apr  3 20:00 000000020000000000000019
-rw------- 1 edbpostgres edbpostgres  16M Apr  4 20:00 00000002000000000000001A
-rw------- 1 edbpostgres edbpostgres  16M Apr  5 20:00 00000002000000000000001B
I know default log file size is 16MB but really dont know why everyday 16MB log file is being created without any transcation.(test environment)

Comment: Well, *some* activity is generated. Use `pg_xlogdump` to read the contents of a WAL archive. Set `archive_mode = off` if you don't care.